# setting width of input tag (Bootstrap4)

Tags: html, css, input, bootstrap-4, size

I am asking user to enter a number .Suppose a user enters 4 ,then is create a 4*4 table using JS.
Every column have a input tag in it . I want the input tag to change it's size according to the size of the column(Size of column will change depending on what number the user enters as the number of columns will change). Is there any bootstrap class that can help me do this . 
(A solution using CSS will also be helpful.)

```
 <div class="col-${12/val} my-col ">
                <input id="00" class="text-center" type="number">
            </div>
```

Comment: add the width of 100% to the input in css, if this is the only element in the coulmn then you can add display: block to input along with width 100% to input

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet

Comment: In bootstrap 4 you can Set the heights of input elements using classes like .input-lg and .input-sm or you can use classes for widths of elements using grid column classes .col-lg-*and .col-sm-*. In CSS you can use media query for different width or input size bu using !important mark in width like: width:30% !important;